# Difference between SparkStreaming and Storm

Tags: apache-storm, spark-streaming

I am doing some analytics on live twitter streaming data.I heard about Spark Streaming.I want to know about which is best for analytics on live streaming data as my data is coming very fast from source.

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed as "opinion based". The answers clearly show the difference between Storm and Spark Streaming and how one is microbatching while the other isn't.

Answer (score 3):

I recommand this presentation about the subject:
http://fr.slideshare.net/ptgoetz/apache-storm-vs-spark-streaming

In fact, apache storm is a true streaming architecture, with events managed one by one, if you want to group them, you have to design a topology for this purpose. It is the most powerful in terms of latency and design. But it is of course complex, and you have to design correctly what you want.

On the other hand, apache spark is a micro-batching architecture, it is like hadoop but executed every x seconds producing micro-batches of data on a defined time window. As it does look like a batching solution, it seems simpler and can be enough if you don't want a latency < few seconds.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from really nice presentation linked by @zenbeni I would like to add a few specific points based on first hand experience with both Storm and Spark streaming especially about your use case (Twitter Data).

- Twitter itself uses Storm for many parts of their realtime stream processing pipeline. So if the type of processing you want to do is similar, Storm is a good choice.
- Storm's multi language support is great. But it is hard to pass around errors. For example, if you are calling Python code from a Java bolt and an exception happens in your Python bolt, it's not easy to propagate this exception back to Java code.
- If your analysis is based on a single Tweet only, Storm will likely be better. However, if you need to do some aggregate or iterative analytics, you will have to microbatch in Storm as well. This essentially means you have to store state in bunch of your bolts.
- Finally, often one needs to do both stream as well as batch processing. Spark shines when you need to mix stream processing along with *batch*, *interactive* and *iterative* processing. In fact, it's not clear to me how you should do iterative processing Storm.